# truffle compile/migrate gives error: "ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library definition."

Tags: solidity, truffle-migration, truffle-compile

The tutorial I'm following created a 2_Migrations.sol with the following:

```
const Token = artifacts.require("Token"); 

module exports = function(deployer) { 
  deployer deploy(Token);
};
```

"Truffle Migrate" gave this error:

```
e:\GitHub\NealWalters\DappUniversity\blockchain-developer-bootcamp>truffle migrate

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling .\src\contracts\1_Migrations.sol
> Compiling .\src\contracts\2_Migrations.sol
> Compiling .\src\contracts\Token.sol

Error: CompileError: /e/GitHub/NealWalters/DappUniversity/blockchain-developer-bootcamp/src/contracts/2_Migrations.sol:3:1: ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library definition.
const Token = artifacts.require("Token");
^---^

Compilation failed. See above.
    at Object.compile (C:\Users\nwalt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\workflow-compile\legacy\index.js:72:1)
Truffle v5.0.40 (core: 5.0.40)
Node v10.16.2
```

If I add the same Pragma that is in 1_migrations.sol (the file generated by truffle init" and renamed):

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.6.0;

const Token = artifacts.require("Token"); 

module exports = function(deployer) { 
  deployer deploy(Token);
};
```

I get the same error.

If I try the same pragma as my Token contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

const Token = artifacts.require("Token"); 

module exports = function(deployer) { 
  deployer deploy(Token);
};
```

Also gives same error.

truffle-config.js contains this for the compiler settings:

```
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is trying to compile migrations scripts as solidity code. That will not work.

Move migrations scripts to the directory `migrations` and rename them with the .js extension.

Your project should look like this

```
migrations\
     1_Migrations.js
     2_Migrations.js

contracts\
     Token.sol
```

Comment: Thanks you, correct.  I noticed that about the same time you posted.  Works now!  And 2_Migrations is .js suffix, not .sol suffix.